# Get the information on each line with the favori button and add favory page with *NgFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

when I click on the button I want it to get the information of the line it is on. for example I want to get the information of that line when I click the button in the first line. my web page is as follows

[website page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8oPw.png)

my html code

```
<table id="news">
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of headers">
            {{col}}
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let new of news">
        <td *ngFor="let col of index">
            {{new[col]}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <button>Favorite</button>
         </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just pass as argument to the function the "new"

```
<button (click)="yourFunction(new)">Favorite</button>
```

You can also pass only the index of the column if you declare in the *ngFor let i=index

```
<!--see the let i=index-->
<tr *ngFor="let new of news; let i=index">
        <td *ngFor="let col of index">
            {{new[col]}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <button (click)="yourFunction(i)>Favorite</button>
         </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" *ngFor="let head of defaultTable.head">{{head}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let body of account ">
            <td >{{body._id}}</td>
            <td >{{body.EmailAddress}}</td>
            <td >{{body.Phone}}</td>
            <td >{{body.Street}}</td>
            <td >{{body.City}}</td>
            <td >{{body.State}}</td>
            <td *ngIf="show">Dactive</td>
            <td *ngIf="!show">Dactive</td>
            <td ><button (click)="Update(body._id)" >Update</button>
              <button (click)="delete(body._id)" >Delete</button></td>
             
            
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: look at my code i use index of  array perhaps it will help you